# AngularJS Providers and Models

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs front-end that talks to a Web API backend.  I am new to this framework and unsure of how to pull complex data from the web api into my application $scope.  I will then be using [this front end library](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/timeline_view.html) to show the data in a calendar widget.

I have a Session table and a Session_Instance table that are linked together with a one to many relationship.  I am able to use $http to get the data then, `$scope.sessions = angular.fromJson(data);` to store it in $scope as an object. The trouble is I want to define methods on this object and pull the code out of the controller so that i can leverage the DI of angular, but I don't know what I should be using or how to do it in Angular.

Is it possible to have complex data models in angular that use providers to keep it up to date in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, the proper angular way to do this would be to wrap your data as a service.

To give an example, here some code copied from [this blog](http://blog.nebithi.com/angularjs-dos-and-donts/):

```
(function () {
    var person = angular.module("person");
    person.factory("PersonService", [
        '$http',
        'httpRestValue',
        function ($http, httpRestValue) {
            var PersonService = {
                data: {
                    currentPerson: {},
                    persons : []
                },
                getPerson: function (id) {
                    return $http.get(httpRestValue + "person/"+id)
                        .success(function success(data) {
                            PersonService.data.currentPerson = data;
                        })
                        .error(function error() {
                        });
                },
                getPersons : function(){
                    return $http.get(httpRestValue + "person/list")
                        .success(function success(data) {
                            PersonService.data.persons = data;
                        })
                        .error(function error() {
                        });
                },
                savePerson : function(person){
                    return $http.post(httpRestValue + "person/",person)
                        .success(function success() {
                            PersonService.getPersons();
                        })
                        .error(function error() {
                        });
                },
                deletePerson : function(id){
                    return $http.delete(httpRestValue + "person/"+id)
                        .success(function success() {
                            PersonService.getPersons();
                        })
                        .error(function error() {
                        });
                }
        };
        return PersonService;
    }
]);
})();
```